# Get info from server-side to my front-end side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using on my back-end node.js and in my front-end a regular js. I was trying to send info from my server by this line:

```
res.status(200).send({ message: "Hello!" });
```

I tried a few codes in my client-side. in the code below I didn't get the message.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(request);
    }
};

request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/newUser');
request.send();
```

this is what I got in my console:

> XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
>   onabort: null
>   onerror: null
>   onload: null
>   onloadend: null
>   onloadstart: null
>   onprogress: null
>   onreadystatechange: ƒ ()
>   arguments: null
>   caller: null
>   length: 0
>   name: ""
>   prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
>   **proto**: ƒ ()
>   [[FunctionLocation]]: newUser.js:111
>   [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
>   ontimeout: null
>   readyState: 4
>   response: "
>   responseText: "
>   responseType: ""
>   responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/newUser"
>   responseXML: null
>   status: 200
>   statusText: "OK"
>   timeout: 0
>   upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, download: > null, …}
>   withCredentials: false
>   **proto**: XMLHttpRequest

I have also tried to use POST instead of GET but I didn't get anything from the console.
Is there any other way to get the massage from the server to my client?

Comment: Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of directly XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @v.kostenko am I suppose to use fetch only in the client-side?

Comment: yes, on server side you don't have native `fetch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this example

```
fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees',{
    method:'GET'
}).then(response => response.json()).then((value)=>{
    console.log(value)
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
})
```